# Not being able to disable dates previous from today using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am having a jquery issue where I am trying to disable the days before today using the .datepicker calendar.

I've tried using `$('.datepicker').datepicker({ startDate: '0d' }).on('changeDate', function(e){$(this).datepicker('hide');`, however this does not seem to be working.

The question is now: Why is it not working and how can I make it?

Here is my code that I am trying to implement it in:

```
<label for="payment">First payment date* </label>
      <div class="input-group amount">
        <input data-format="date" type="text" name="FirstPayDate" placeholder="First payment date*" class="datepicker form-control" 
        onsubmit="return validateForm()"id="firstPayDate" value="%%=v(@firstPayDate)=%%" required>
```

EDIT: I've edited the code given to show the original line of code where I am trying to implement the startDate.

Comment: The `onsubmit` handler is only for `<form>` elements.

Comment: Your code works as such: https://jsfiddle.net/15ppq2m5/ The problem is somewhere you're not showing.

Comment: (Note that it won't work if you've already initialized the datepicker before. The options must be given at initialization.)

Comment: I see, it may be due to the extra code that I've added along with the minDate. Could this be the issue? Also how would I provide the options in initialization?

Comment: Um... just like you've just done?

Answer (score 1):

Set the minDate value to 0.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Source: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `startDate`. Checkout: https://jsfiddle.net/s1ytztux/

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 startDate: '0d'
});
```